# Fill exchange account fields intent extra on android 4.0

Tags: exchange-server, account, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Does anybody know how to pre-fill fields using extra in intent when calling

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.ADD_ACCOUNT_SETTINGS");
```

to set up a Exchange account ?

```
intent.putExtra("EMAIL", "plop");
intent.putExtra("USER", "stars");
```

does not work.

HELP ME !!

NB :

```
login : d@d.d 
pwd : debug
```

allow you to activate debug info.